# static x = ( { y } ) => { ... }の仕組みについて

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbaZs1dzsVo

上記react native参考動画の

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {...}
```

の部分なのですが、navigationを引数に受け取れる仕組みが理解出来ません。
そもそも変数を{}で囲むとどういった動きをするのでしょうか。
これはreact native独自の仕様なのか、それともJSの仕様なのでしょうか。

何をキーワードに検索したら良いかもわからず困っています。
仕様の詳細が載っている文献がありましたら、ご紹介頂きたいです。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[引数の分割代入](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)といいます。

以下、サンプルです。

```
// 引数で指定されたオブジェクトのうち、nameプロパティのみ利用する
const f1 = ({ name }) => { return "hello " + name + "!!" }
obj = { age: 12, name: 'hoge' }
f1(obj)
```

> "hello hoge!!"

以下のような分割代入を関数の引数に適応したものです。

```
var o = {p: 42, q: true};
var {p, q} = o;

console.log(p); // 42
console.log(q); // true
```

JavaScriptは言語仕様が、ここ4、5年で大きく進化しています(ES2015,ES2016,ES2017など)。なので、一度、最近のJavaScriptについて書かれた参考書などを読まれると良いと思います。
(私は最近のJavaScriptについて学ぶために、[初めてのJavaScript 第3版 ――ES2015以降の最新ウェブ開発](https://www.oreilly.co.jp/books/9784873117836/) を購入しました。他にも良い本があると思います。)